# Row/column grouping in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have been trying to figure out the proper way to display a table in SSRS 2008, but am having little luck. I have a basic table that looks like the following:

[image: Table]

I have two row groups, one on the TML field and the other on the Reading. I have one column group on Inspection Date.

Here is what my table looks like on the report itself:

[image: Incorrect Table]

I'd like the readings to be on the same line as reading number for each inspection date, but can't figure out how to get them that way.

Here is what the dataset looks like:

[image: Dataset]

Any ideas as to how to group them properly so they display on the same lines?

Comment: You could just use a matrix instead of a table. Have your InspectionDate be the column, your ReadingNumber be the rows, and your data be the values you want (MAX(Reading)?)

Comment: I think you want the **TML** and **Spool** to be **ROW** Groups like you have and **Reading Number** then **Date** as **Column** Groups.

Comment: @ZLK If you want to post your comment as an answer I was able to get it figured out. Just had to add a parent group (TML) to Reading Number. Thank you!